# Facing Exception with Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am trying to test a web service for a web app. written in asp.net c#, WCF
i am facing this exception:

> The HTTP request to 'http://localhost:36162/Services/Service1.svc' has exceeded the allotted timeout. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I'm looking at how to resolve this. It's now taking more than 10 minutes.

Comment: This is a very generic error that can occur due to a whole lot of reasons. Starting with mis-configuration to database optimization issues. Please provide us with more information, including the binding configuration of the service/client. The code that you're calling which is taking so long to respond, etc...

Comment: What is your question?  Are you wanting to increase the timeout, or are you wanting to fix the service so it doesn't time out?  If it's the latter, we'll need to see the actual service code.

Comment: A web service that takes more than 10 minutes? This probably shouldn't be a web service.

Comment: Also, you meant "WCF", not "WPF".

Comment: @DarinDimitrov You could explain more. It is still OK to expose a long-running operation with a web service, but some changes would be good. You should probably provide the client with a correlation identifier, and perhaps an estimate on when to check back - then run the long running task in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug the service by putting a breakpoint in the service and verify its returning data in a timely fashion from a call from the client.

If it is returning data in a timely fashion you have a configuration problem with the client (maybe the buffer overflow then set size).

Or use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look at the traffic to see if data is returning in a timely fashion.

Regardless that will give you an indication of where the problem lies.

EDIT: Also use the [WCF test client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to remove the caller from the equation. That is a great tool to use.